# What does C++03 12.4/12 say about calling a base class destructor explicitly through the pointer?

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior

According to C++03 12.4/12 when a destructor is invoked explicitly

> if the object is not of the destructor’s class type and not of a class derived from the destructor’s class type, the program has undefined behavior

So I have this code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

char memory[100];
new(memory) Derived();
Base* ptr = (Base*)memory;
ptr->~Base();
```

Here the object is of type `Derived` and "the destructor's class type" is `Base` and so it looks like according to the Standard wording there're no grounds for UB.

So does the code above yield UB according to the Standard?

Comment: do derived usually provide some members?

Comment: @itwasntpete: Well, not necessarily. You could for example craft a new exception class that can be caught separately without adding any new members.

Comment: I've got a hunch that this is UB because 12.4/12 allows the form `derivedPtr->~Base()` with the intent of supporting virtual destructors. Don't have C++03 available here, though.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, there's no undefined behavior.

By contrast there is potential UB in this case depending on the types involved:

```
Base *ptr = new Derived();
delete ptr;
```

The reason is that for some types an adjustment might have been applied by the implementation to get from `Derived*` to `Base*`. So without the pointer to the complete object there's no way to free the memory allocation correctly. A virtual destructor ensures that the `Base` sub-object provides enough information for the implementation to recover that (the virtual call mechanism must be able to recover the `Derived*` pointer in order to pass it as `this`).

But in your example the memory isn't freed and so there's no motivation to make it UB. Of course it's still a bad idea, since conceptually the `Derived` object is in a broken state. You have no legitimate way to call `~Derived`, even. In your example though both types are trivially destructible, so there's no *need* to call the destructor of either.

Comment: Emmm... Adjustment? `Derived` can easily have `operator new()` implemented on another heap and that would cause dire consequences even without any adjustment.

Comment: @sharptooth: yes, good point. If `new` and `delete` are not overloaded for these types though, then it's still UB for my reason.

Comment: Actually the new-delete example is UB anyway. Your example and my example are just examples of what can break.

Comment: @sharptooth: yes, the reason I raised it is because it has a rationale for being UB. Without knowing that rationale, people might think that your example ought to be UB too since it's superficially similar to a case they're told is UB early and often by any reliable book or teacher. Ofc I somewhat undermined this plan by only providing part of the rationale...

Answer (score 1):

It's not UB, since both classes have trivial destructors, and therefore calling the destructor has the same effect as *not* calling the destructor (and *not* calling the destructor is certainly not UB).

Comment: Does that also apply in `Base* base = new Derived(); delete base;` case?

Comment: @sharptooth: I would go so far as to say yes; in fact, I would think `Base base; static_cast<Derived *>(&base)->~Derived();` should work as well (as absurd as it sounds) because both of them have trivial destructors, which means their destructors must have no effect...

Comment: The text from the standard that's quoted in the question does not have an exception for trivial destructors. This answer is **not** about undefined behavior, but about likely consequences of the code.

Answer (score 0):

please correct me if i'm wrong, i think there isn't undefined behavior but still should be avoided in sence of humanity (or maintainablity). but, consider `Derived` is creating some kind of member, e.g. a shared pointer, (which is not untypical even for exceptions :). i tried this code on my machine and also on [codepad](http://codepad.org/01PRYPiv):

```
class Base {
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<int> x;
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<int> y;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  boost::shared_ptr<int> xx(new int(0xff));
  boost::shared_ptr<int> yy(new int(0xaa));

  int memory[100];
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    memory[i] = 0;
  Derived* foo = new(memory) Derived();
  foo->x = xx;
  foo->y = yy;
  (*foo->y)--;
  Base* ptr = (Base*)foo;

  ptr->~Base();

  Derived* bar = new(memory) Derived();

  bar->x = xx;
  bar->y = yy;

  foo->~Derived();

  return 0;
}
```

here is that the shared_ptr **yy** isn't released, and nobody could guarantee to never forget about Derived shouldn't provide any kind of stuff.

Comment: Something not released doesn't mean UB.

Comment: In this case I *think* the UB is constructing an object over the memory occupied by a non-trivially-destructible object that hasn't been destroyed. So I *think* the UB is the second call to `new(memory) Derived()` that scribbles over the `y` member. But even if I'm wrong and that's not UB, then `bar->y` is null so dereferencing it is. [That remark is on the codepad code, I just noticed the code here is different.]